# Jquery multiple tooltips

Tags: jquery, html

Tryed get multiple tooltips for last 2 hours but still cannot done last part of my project so I decide to ask for help.

example of work can be find on http://titan.maxko.org/?page=search&item=tier when you hover GROUP icon it show images than again hover over any image and it will work but problem is it dosen't convert html tags as it was done on first hover. In short tooltip inside tooltip dosen't convert html tags.

my code:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
          $.widget("ui.tooltip", $.ui.tooltip, {
              options: {
                  content: function () {
                      return $(this).prop('title');
                  }
              }
          });

          $( "[title]" )
            .bind( "mouseleave", function( event ) {

                var test = $(this).attr('class');
                if(test != "group")
                    return;

                event.stopImmediatePropagation();

                var fixed = setTimeout('$("[title]").tooltip("close")', 50);

                $(".ui-tooltip").hover(
                    function(){clearTimeout (fixed);},
                    function(){$("[title]").tooltip("close");}
                );
            }).tooltip();

      });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you use event.stopImmediatePropagation() ?
What is the hove inside hte mouseleave good for ?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Generate traffic to your page ?
Your question makes no sense neither does your implementation. Sorry, but maybe you can try to explain, what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: Using opImmediatePropagation() to hold opened title so I can again hover. Lets me try explain with images maybe will be able to understand.

When you go on web you see http://screencast.com/t/6ntxYF0BAP now find icon GROUP and hover over it as on image http://screencast.com/t/w39iypcmFkoY , now again hover over new image and thare is problem when hover over tooltip html tags is not converted http://screencast.com/t/QHkWRKrXc4 but need be like when hover first time http://screencast.com/t/LVRXa6zPg9Qi . do you now better understand?

p.s: guy who edited he broke a little question :)

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems your challenge has different aspects.
I would just argue, that you might check the documentation at https://api.jqueryui.com/1.9/tooltip/

At first, you should not need to use stopPropagation and tooltip.close() in your scenario.

Try the following: 
Use the supplied events, like tooltipclose and the alike.
Initialize the handlers with the initialization of the plugin via its configuration object.

You generally do not need to use timeout, use

```
$( ".selector" ).tooltip({
  hide: { effect: "explode", duration: 1000 }
});
```

and

```
$( ".selector" ).tooltip({
  show: { effect: "blind", duration: 800 }
});
```

to let the plugin handle a fadeOut or similar.

You can change the default linkage to the [title] of an element to any selector you need. Eg. for newly created elements.

```
$( ".selector" ).tooltip({
  items: "img[alt]"
});
```

To bind a handler to **dynamically** created dom elements, use

```
jQuery.on()
```

method. See http://api.jquery.com/on/ , as bind() will not work for this.

In general, you will want to bind the handler to every new and old element of a certain class or type while interacting with the user.

Use

```
$(this)
```

to refer to the current element inside your handlers.

Comment: thanks for answer, already read about popup function. Maybe you didnt understand the best question please check my comments but in short my problem is html inside second tooltip http://screencast.com/t/QHkWRKrXc4